# How to convert anonymos type json to object class in c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I have an data get from my database. Here is my data formatted. I tried a lot of solutions on the internet but it didn't work.
Here is my code:

- RoleService

```
public async Task<object> GetById(int id)
    {
        var rolePermissions = await _permissionRepository.GetAllNonTracking()
            .Where(x => x.RoleId == id)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Id = x.RoleId,
                Name = x.Role.Name,
                Description = x.Role.Description,
                PermissionId = Enum.GetName((PermissionType)x.PermissionId),
                ModuleId = Enum.GetName((CAModules)x.ModuleId),
            })
            .ToListAsync();
        var rolePermissionFormatted = rolePermissions.GroupBy(x => new {
            x.Id,
            x.Name,
            x.Description
            })
            .Select(gcs => new {
                Id = gcs.Key.Id,
                Name = gcs.Key.Name,
                Description = gcs.Key.Description,
                PermissionRoles = gcs.Select(p => new
                {
                    p.ModuleId,
                    p.PermissionId
                }).ToList().GroupBy(x => new
                {
                    ModuleName = x.ModuleId
                }).Select(per => new
                {
                    ModuleName = per.Key.ModuleName,
                    Permission = per.Select(x => x.PermissionId)
                })
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        return rolePermissionFormatted;
    }
```

- output from postman:

```
{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Marker",
        "description": "Marker dessc",
        "permission_roles": [
            {
                "module_name": "Event",
                "permission": [
                    "ReadOnly"
                ]
            },
            {
                "module_name": "Report",
                "permission": [
                    "ReadOnly",
                    "ReadWrite"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

- convert json to class in https://json2csharp.com/

```
public class DetailRoleDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<PermissionRole> PermissionRoles { get; set; }
}

public class PermissionRole
{
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Permission { get; set; }
}
```

How to convert rolePermissionFormatted to DetailRoleDto. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I don't understand. Why? Wouldn't it be easier just to `new` the type you actually want? Or actually create a proper type in C# to represent what you get from the database, and then use a tool like AutoMapper to map to your DTO, keeping the separation.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I want out put of api is DTO. Not like object. Are you suggest here ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solutions:

```
var detailRoleDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DetailRoleDto(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rolePermissionFormatted
));
```

Comment: This seems to defeat the point of using a DTO in the first place, as it requires that `rolePermissionFormatted` has to serialize to the same thing that `DetailRoleDto` would. This solution will also be pretty slow because you have to convert data to a string and back.